# How to unfold a template to string when the possible type be float or string?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In C++, i want to build a string only container from a template.

For example:

```
template<typename T>
void show(const T & t) {  // the T can be map<string, string> or <string, float> or <string, int>
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> r;
  for (const auto & i : t) {
     const auto & j = i.first;
     const auto & k = i.second;  //  TODO: how to
     // make k as string, possible type of k can be 
     // int float or string???
     // put them into r
  }
  return r;
}
```

How can i implement this?

Comment: Can you use C++17?

Comment: @NathanOliver I perfer c++11, but is considering to use c++17 in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF you can use C++17, then [constexpr if statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) is what you want.  That would give you

```
template<typename T> // the T can be map<string, string> or <string, float> or <string, int>
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> show(const T & t) {  
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> r;
  for (const auto & i : t) {
     const auto & j = i.first;
     const auto & k = i.second;
     if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(k)>, std::string>)
       r.insert(std::make_pair(j, k));
     else
       r.insert(std::make_pair(j, std::to_string(k)));
  }
  return r;
}
```

If you want to use C++11, you can use a template plus an overload to handle the dispatch like

```
template<typename T>
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> show(const std::map<std::string, T> & t) {  
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> r;
  for (const auto & i : t) {
     const auto & j = i.first;
     const auto & k = i.second;
     r.insert(std::make_pair(j, std::to_string(k)));
  }
  return r;
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> show(const std::map<std::string, std::string> & t) {  
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> r;
  for (const auto & i : t) {
     const auto & j = i.first;
     const auto & k = i.second;
     r.insert(std::make_pair(j, k));
  }
  return r;
}
```

This works because when a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` is passed, it is an exact match to the non-function template, and that takes precedence over the function template.

Comment: In C++17, we can also declar the `first` , `second` by structured binding. Secondly I personally prefer `std::map::emplce` for in place construction, if the key-value pair is easily not so complicated type.